# How to stop inserting data in mysql recursively

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

***This prints job description,job id and job name from mysql database. It also has button on click user can select a job***

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT  jid,name, description FROM jobs";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>

<div class="product-card">

  <div class="product-details">
    <h1 id="jid-<?php print($record['jid']); ?>" ><?php echo $record['jid']; ?></h1>
    <h1 id="name-<?php print($record['jid']); ?>"><?php echo $record['name']; ?></h1>
    <p id="description-<?php print($record['jid']); ?>"><?php echo $record['description'];?></p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" id="submit-<?php echo $record['jid'];?>" />
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit-<?php echo $record['jid'];?>").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();insert_job_f(<?php print($record['jid']); ?>);
});
</script>

<?php 
} ?>
```

*****This is jquery script*****

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert_job_f(jid)
{
  //debugger;
 var jidVal=$("#jid-"+jid).val();

  $.ajax
  ({
  type:'post',
  url:'insert_job.php',
  data:{
   insert_job:"insert_job",

   jid:jidVal
  },
  success:function(response) {
    alert(response);
    if(response=="success")
    {

      //window.location.href="main.php";
    }
    else
    {
      //alert("Wrong Details");
    }
  }
  });
}
</script>
```

*****insert_job.php****

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['jid']))
{
 $host="localhost";
 $username="Ahad";
 $password="abc.123";
 $databasename="vsm";
 $connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
 $db=mysqli_select_db($connect,$databasename);

 $h=$_POST['jid'];[enter image description here][1]

$select_data=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ff (jid) VALUES (19)"); 



 if($select_data===FALSE)
 {

    echo mysqli_error($connect); 

    exit();
 }
 else
 {


    echo "successfully registered";

 }
 exit();
}
?>
```

How can i make it send the data once it is sending the hard coded value again and again in a loop

This image below is showing the hard coded value used for testing is going in data base recursively
[image]

Comment: Remove the `$().click` function outside of your `while` loop.

Comment: if i remove $().click there will be no event occuring

Comment: can u tell me where exactly i can put my button if i take it off from while loop button wount be visible on the form

Answer (score 0):

Remove this completely

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit-<?php echo $record['jid'];?>").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();insert_job_f(<?php print($record['jid']); ?>);
});
</script>
```

and attach the `onclick` event directly to your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Select" id="submit-<?php echo $record['jid'];?>" onclick="insert_job_f(<?php print($record['jid']); ?>)" />
```

I'm not sure how to handle `preventDefault()` but you can probably attach it to the `insert_job_f()` function.

Comment: echo "successfully registered";
 is coming again and again

Comment: Does the loop stop and if so, when? Also, are your `jid`'s unique?

Comment: loop does not stop yes jid are unique when i press select button alert comes again and again " successfully registered"